# T-SQL Inserting records to our ERP, checking for duplicates

Tags: t-sql

Inserting records to our ERP, I need to check for duplicates. PC is our Enterprise Resource Planning (ERP). GM is our Customer Relationship Management (CRM) PCB is our Bridge that we are using to synchronize updating between our ERP and CRM. Which is better? Method 1 or Method 2

PC is our ERP,
GM is our CRM,
PCB is our Bridge

SQL Server 2008r

```
Method 1
       IF New PCB.People_ID <> PC.PeopleID (1) --People_ID not Duplicate
          IF -- Next Check Name
        A.  or PCB FIRST_NAME <> PC FIRST_NAME (2)  
        B.  or PCB MIDDLE_NAME <> PC MIDDLE_NAME (2) 
        C.  or PCB LAST_NAME <> PC LAST_NAME (2)
          --Name Not Duplicate
             IF PCB @TAX_ID <> PC @P_TAX_ID (3)  --Next  Check  TAX_ID
                         --TAX_ID not  Duplicate
               Create New Record  sp_insert_people (15)
           Send PC.PeopleID to GM GM.U_KEY4
                    THEN 
                          Send back the 99-SSN to GM Status (6)
                    ENDIF
          THEN –Name is Duplicate
                 ABC Matching Names  send 99-NAM to GM Status (5)
             ENDIF
        THEN --People_ID is Duplicate (7)
          IF – Next Check Name 
        A.  or PCB FIRST_NAME <> PC FIRST_NAME (2) 
        B.  or PCB MIDDLE_NAME <> PC MIDDLE_NAME (2) 
        C.  or PCB LAST_NAME <> PC LAST_NAME (2)
          --Name not Duplicate
          send 99-NAM to GM Status (14)
         THEN
             IF PCB @TAX_ID <> PC @P_TAX_ID (3)  --Next  Check  TAX_ID
                          --TAX_ID not  Duplicate
                             send back the 99-SSN to Status GM.KEY1 (13)
                    THEN  --TAX_ID Was Not Duplicate
                           --Check Date of Birth
                IF CG BIRTH_DATE <> PC P_BIRTH_DATE (10)
                   send back 99-DOB to GM Status  Status GM.KEY1 (16)
                            THEN
                                 Update Record  sp_insert_people (11)
                            ENDIF –Date of Birth
                     ENDIF –TAX_ID
        ENDIF   
            Record was not created or updated for some reason other than listed above send back 99-OTHER  (17) To GM Status
        ENDIF

Method 2

    --  Start Check Comparison People Information
        DECLARE @p_list_people_changes TABLE(PEOPLE_ID VARCHAR(200));

        INSERT INTO @p_list_people_changes SELECT PEOPLE_ID FROM PEOPLECHANGES; --Some condition will add to reduce list

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION;

        CREATE TABLE #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION 
        (
            PEOPLE_ID VARCHAR(200),
            USTUSTATDT DATETIME,
            RESPOND_CODE VARCHAR(20),
            ACT CHAR(1) --I: INSERT, U: UPDATE, E: ERROR
        );

        DECLARE @p_PEOPLE_ID VARCHAR(200);  
        SELECT TOP 1 @p_PEOPLE_ID = PEOPLE_ID FROM @p_list_people_changes;

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_bridge_people_change') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tmp_bridge_people_change;
        SELECT t.* INTO #tmp_bridge_people_change FROM PEOPLECHANGES t 
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT PEOPLE_ID, MAX(USTUSTATDT) USTUSTATDT  FROM PEOPLECHANGES
        GROUP BY PEOPLE_ID) t1 ON t.PEOPLE_ID = t1.PEOPLE_ID AND t.USTUSTATDT = t1.USTUSTATDT
        ;

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_powercampus_people') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tmp_powercampus_people;
        SELECT * INTO #tmp_powercampus_people FROM PC.dbo.PEOPLE;


        --Get list of new People
        INSERT INTO #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION (PEOPLE_ID, USTUSTATDT, RESPOND_CODE, ACT)
        SELECT br.PEOPLE_ID, br.USTUSTATDT, NULL, 'I' FROM #tmp_bridge_people_change br
        LEFT JOIN #tmp_powercampus_people pw ON br.PEOPLE_ID = pw.PEOPLE_ID
        WHERE pw.PEOPLE_ID IS NULL;

        --Get list of update/error People
        INSERT INTO #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION (PEOPLE_ID, USTUSTATDT, RESPOND_CODE, ACT)
        SELECT br.PEOPLE_ID, br.USTUSTATDT,
        CASE 
                WHEN (br.FIRST_NAME = pw.FIRST_NAME AND br.MIDDLE_NAME = pw.MIDDLE_NAME AND br.LAST_NAME = pw.LAST_NAME)
                     AND (br.TAX_ID = pw.TAX_ID) 
                     AND (br.BIRTH_DATE = pw.BIRTH_DATE)
                THEN 
                    NULL
                ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN (br.FIRST_NAME <> pw.FIRST_NAME OR br.MIDDLE_NAME <> pw.MIDDLE_NAME OR br.LAST_NAME <> pw.LAST_NAME)
                        THEN '99-NAM'
                        WHEN (br.FIRST_NAME = pw.FIRST_NAME AND br.MIDDLE_NAME = pw.MIDDLE_NAME AND br.LAST_NAME = pw.LAST_NAME)
                                 AND (br.TAX_ID <> pw.TAX_ID)
                        THEN '99-SSN'
                        WHEN (br.FIRST_NAME = pw.FIRST_NAME AND br.MIDDLE_NAME = pw.MIDDLE_NAME AND br.LAST_NAME = pw.LAST_NAME)
                                 AND (br.TAX_ID = pw.TAX_ID) 
                                 AND (br.BIRTH_DATE <> pw.BIRTH_DATE)
                        THEN '99-DOB'
                        END
            END RESPOND_CODE, 
            CASE 
                WHEN (br.FIRST_NAME = pw.FIRST_NAME AND br.MIDDLE_NAME = pw.MIDDLE_NAME AND br.LAST_NAME = pw.LAST_NAME)
                     AND (br.TAX_ID = pw.TAX_ID) 
                     AND (br.BIRTH_DATE = pw.BIRTH_DATE)
                THEN 
                    'U'
                ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN NOT(br.FIRST_NAME <> pw.FIRST_NAME OR br.MIDDLE_NAME <> pw.MIDDLE_NAME OR br.LAST_NAME <> pw.LAST_NAME)
                        THEN 'E'
                        WHEN NOT((br.FIRST_NAME <> pw.FIRST_NAME OR br.MIDDLE_NAME <> pw.MIDDLE_NAME OR br.LAST_NAME <> pw.LAST_NAME)
                                 AND (br.TAX_ID <> pw.TAX_ID))
                        THEN 'E'
                        WHEN NOT((br.FIRST_NAME <> pw.FIRST_NAME OR br.MIDDLE_NAME <> pw.MIDDLE_NAME OR br.LAST_NAME <> pw.LAST_NAME)
                                 AND (br.TAX_ID <> pw.TAX_ID) 
                                 AND (br.BIRTH_DATE <> pw.BIRTH_DATE))
                        THEN 'E'
                        END
            END ACT
        FROM #tmp_bridge_people_change br
        INNER JOIN #tmp_powercampus_people pw ON br.PEOPLE_ID = pw.PEOPLE_ID
    --  End Check Comparison People Information

    --  Start Action after Comparison
    --  IF FALSE RAISE MESSEAGE TO UPDATE GM STATUS
        BEGIN TRY
            UPDATE c
            SET c.KEY1 = tmp.RESPOND_CODE
            FROM #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION tmp
            JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.CONTACT1 c   ON  tmp.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4
            WHERE tmp.ACT = 'E';
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            UPDATE c
            SET c.KEY1 = '99-OVR'
            FROM #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION tmp
            JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.CONTACT1 c   ON  tmp.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4
            WHERE tmp.ACT = 'E';
        END CATCH

    --  IF TRUE NEW RECORD THEN INSERT INTO PowerCampus
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO PC.dbo.People --People
              (PEOPLE_CODE,
               PEOPLE_ID,
               PEOPLE_CODE_ID,
               FIRST_NAME,
               MIDDLE_NAME,
               LAST_NAME,
               CREATE_DATE,
               CREATE_TIME...) 
              SELECT PEOPLE_CODE,
                     PEOPLE_ID,
                     PEOPLE_CODE_ID,
                     FIRST_NAME,
                     MIDDLE_NAME,
                     LAST_NAME,
                     CREATE_DATE,
                     CREATE_TIME,
                     'PERM'...
                FROM Bridge_test.dbo.PEOPLECHANGES t
               WHERE (Processed is Null) 
               AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION tmp WHERE tmp.ACT = 'I' AND t.PEOPLE_ID = tmp.PEOPLE_ID AND t.USTUSTATDT = tmp.USTUSTATDT);

            --Send PEOPLE_ID to GM - I don't know what extractly information which you want to send
            INSERT INTO GoldMine_test.dbo.CONTACT1 (KEY4) 
            SELECT PEOPLE_ID FROM #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION tmp
            WHERE tmp.ACT = 'I';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            INSERT INTO GoldMine_test.dbo.CONTACT1 (KEY4, U_KEY4) 
            SELECT PEOPLE_ID, '99-OVR' U_KEY4 FROM #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION tmp
            WHERE tmp.ACT = 'I';
        END CATCH

    --  IF TRUE EXISTS RECORD THEN UPDATE PowerCampus
        BEGIN TRY

            UPDATE c
                SET    c.PEOPLE_CODE = pc.PEOPLE_CODE,
                       --c.PEOPLE_ID = pc.,
                       c.PEOPLE_CODE_ID = pc.PEOPLE_CODE_ID,
                       c.FIRST_NAME = pc.FIRST_NAME,
                       c.MIDDLE_NAME = pc.MIDDLE_NAME,
                       c.LAST_NAME = pc.LAST_NAME,
                       c.CREATE_DATE = pc.CREATE_DATE,
                       c.CREATE_TIME = pc.CREATE_TIME...
            FROM PC.dbo.PEOPLE c
            INNER JOIN #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION tmp ON c.PEOPLE_ID = tmp.PEOPLE_ID AND tmp.ACT = 'U'
            INNER JOIN Bridge_Test.dbo.PEOPLECHANGES pc ON tmp.PEOPLE_ID = pc.PEOPLE_ID AND tmp.USTUSTATDT = pc.USTUSTATDT
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            UPDATE c
            SET c.U_KEY4 = '99-OVR'
            FROM #TMP_LIST_PEOPLE_ACTION tmp
            JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.CONTACT1 c   ON  tmp.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4
            WHERE tmp.ACT = 'U';
        END CATCH
    --  End Action after Comparison


    END
    GO
```

Comment: Method 3 is better.

Comment: Post the actual code with sample data.

Comment: Why not use the API? Also, what are GM and PCB?

Comment: GM is GoldMine CRM. PCB is a table in our bridge database that contains the new records from GoldMine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerCampus has a number of built-in stored procedures for duplicate checking that you should consider before trying to write your own:

```
[dbo].[spExistDuplicatePeople]
[dbo].[spFindDuplicatePeople]
[dbo].[spSelDuplicatePeopleByBatch]
[WebServices].[spSelTranscriptStudent]
```

Also, you should use a built-in procedure for inserting records in the PEOPLE table, such as `[WebServices].[spInsPerson]`.